# external monitor dont work only with my laptop but it work with another laptops

Tags: laptop, display

I want to connect my laptop with external monitors, to have the ability to work on 2 screens, but for some reason it does not work with my laptop.

If I plug the monitor in another laptop it works.

On my laptop the moniter gives me "no signal". Even after I found it in display settings. I tried to change the VGA cable and play with setting but no result.

Answer (score -1):

Try pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. That is how you cycle through the monitor output options in Windows.

Comment: yes , i tried it but it didnt work . thank you !